# how fast a firewall/DPI system can find an ssh server IP on a random port

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, dpi

Sniffing SSH traffic on port `22` to determine the server IP address should not be hard for any firewalls/DPI systems.
I am wondering if the port is **random** thus we have around 60k possibilities, how (fast) a freiwall/DPI system can find the SSH server ip address.

Comment: use "nmap -Pn ip_addr"

Comment: This depends on too many factors such as the network quality and intervening devices.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a 100% correct answer, but I prefer to put it here in case anyone else had this question

We know SSH is made to a server using TCP and we know TCP has payload, the actual data that is sent to a peer. It seems SSH first payload tells about its version.  For example **SSH-2.0**. Thus

- if we capture the first packet that payload is not 0, and
- that payload contained "SSH-2.0"

We can tell this an SSH tunnel and determine the SSH server IP address

---

Let see it in action

#### string "SSH-2.0" to hax

```
echo "SSH-2.0" | hexdump -C -n 7
00000000  53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30                              |SSH-2.0|
00000007
```

#### capture first non-zero payload (just 1 packet)

```
tcpdump -vv -X -n -i wlp2s0  -c 1 "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-push) != 0 and port 22" 
tcpdump: listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:27:32.609719 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 19848, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 73)
    192.168.1.109.47574 > ADDRESS:PORT Flags [P.], cksum 0x1dc7 (correct), seq 3554308024:3554308045, ack 3135539829, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 2550455211 ecr 2971629478], length 21
    0x0000:  4548 0049 4d88 4000 4006 3fbc c0a8 016d  EH.IM.@.@.?....m
    0x0010:  576b 93a2 b9d6 03dd d3da 6fb8 bae4 8a75  Wk........o....u
    0x0020:  8018 01f6 1dc7 0000 0101 080a 9804 dbab  ................
    0x0030:  b11f 77a6 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  ..w.SSH-2.0-Open     <== here
    0x0040:  5353 485f 392e 350d 0a                   SSH_9.5..
1 packet captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

As we can see these sequences `5353 482d 322e 30` represent "SSH-2.0" in ASCII. Here we rely on port 22 to capture the data.

My initial question was what if the port is random? How to determine SSH traffic without knowing the port?

#### tcpdump payload filter

I found that to determine a SSH connection we do not need the port. We can directly match/filter the "SSH-2.0" string in a payload

```
tcpdump -vv -X -n -i wlp2s0  -c 1 'tcp[32:4] = 0x5353482d'
```

here we match just 1 packet if 4 bytes of payload contains `0x5353482d` which is "SSH-" in ASCII. And the result is the same. Look for `5353 482d`

```
    0x0000:  4548 0049 e6fe 4000 4006 a645 c0a8 016d  EH.I..@.@..E...m
    0x0010:  576b 93a2 aa4e 03dd 349a 8f97 c475 a3f3  Wk...N..4....u..
    0x0020:  8018 01f6 f39e 0000 0101 080a 9859 2657  .............Y&W
    0x0030:  b173 c254 5353 482d 322e 302d 4f70 656e  .s.TSSH-2.0-Open     <== here
    0x0040:  5353 485f 392e 350d 0a                   SSH_9.5..
1 packet captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

---

Conclusion (mine)

For a firewall/DPI system the SSH port does not matter if we leave it as it is (22) or change it to a random one since by looking at first non-zero payload we can find SSH connection

*please correct me if you found better test/explanation*